# Remove Spacing or Padding in android Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I'm using android spinner and edittext from support lib v21. I would like to align text to left the same like edittext as shown in figure. But, deafult spinner include spacing or padding. So, I would like to remove it to align text to left. Please help how to remove it.

[image]

Comment: You can customize your own Spinner via Nine patch and specify padding

Answer (score 29):

In your SpinnerAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        view.setPadding(0, view.getPaddingTop(), view.getPaddingRight(), view.getPaddingBottom());
        return view;
}
```

Comment: Worked in my case.. but maybe super view is unnecessary. Just setting  'convertView.setPadding()' should work.

Comment: @Chan which adapter do you use here?

Comment: @VolodymyrKhodonovych SpinnerAdapter

Answer (score 9):

This array adapter removes left padding in Android Spinner.

Kotlin version:

```
open class NoPaddingArrayAdapter<T>(context: Context, layoutId: Int, items: List<T>?) : ArrayAdapter<T>(context, layoutId, items) {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
        val view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
        view.setPadding(0,view.paddingTop,view.paddingRight,view.paddingBottom)
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest answer

Comment: Perfect Solution!

Answer (score 5):

You can also remove the padding of spinner in xml

Only need to set padding to 0dp.

```
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:padding="0dp"     
        android:id="@+id/my_spinner">
```

Comment: Doesn't work. OP is asking about the padding of the text INSIDE the spinner, not the spinner itself.

Answer (score 4):

The layout for `TextView` that is displayed in your `Spinner` comes from your `SpinnerAdapter`, which provides 2 methods:

- `getView(position, convertView, parent)`: returns View for collapsed state, you can override this to return different layouts for different selected item
- `getDropdownView(position, convertView, parent)`: return View for each dropdown item in expanded state (after you click Spinner to open popup/dialog for selection)

In your case you should override your `SpinnerAdapter.getView(position, convertView, parent)` and inflate the layout with padding/spacing of your choice.

For example:

```
spinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
class MyAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false);
        }
        // bind your data here
        return convertView;
    }
    // other implementation
}
```

**res/layout/spinner_item.xml**

```
<!-- set padding margin whatever here -->
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

You can also conveniently use one of the framework provided [`SpinnerAdapter` indirect subclasses](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html) (`ArrayAdapter<T>, BaseAdapter, CursorAdapter, ResourceCursorAdapter, SimpleAdapter, SimpleCursorAdapter, ThemedSpinnerAdapter`), just make sure to supply the correct layout that would be used by `getView()` method.

Answer (score 4):

This Kotlin code is a little bit more succinct than the `getView` override in another answer.
It makes it a bit more clear in fewer lines that it is mostly just doing what super does, except that it also overrides `setPadding`for the left value.

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent).apply {
        setPadding(0, paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom)
    }
}
```

Here is my full fragment code that uses a data binding object for the complete spinner array adapter override, which also does a selected item and an alternating background color in `getDropDownView`:

```
binding.editSpinner.apply {
    this.context ?: return@apply
    this.adapter = object : ArrayAdapter<Any>(
        requireContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
        SpinnerTypeValues.values().map { it.text }
    ) {
        override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
            return super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent).also {
                when {
                    position == this@apply.selectedItemPosition -> it.setBackgroundColor( Color.rgb(245, 212, 119) )
                    position % 2 == 0 -> it.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(240, 240, 240))
                    else -> it.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(214, 235, 189))
                }
            }
        }
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
            return super.getView(position, convertView, parent).apply {
                setPadding(0, paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom)
            }
        }
    }
    this.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            viewModel.saveSpinnerSelection(position)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code to do so. Change style attribute in your spinner list item layout to textViewStyle as below

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/textViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item layout from code by new spinner_item layout

Code for spinner_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/primaryText"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

This will remove an extra margin and you can style it according to your requirement.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

1. Create custom layout(as you need) for spinner row.
2. inflate the layout when you set the data adapter to the spinner.

Answer (score 1):

If yo don't want to mess in Java Code and have it in styles

Search for this file (Cmd+Shift+O)
`abc_spinner_textfield_background_material.xml`

and copy to your project. Remove all *inset* values from root element and refer the file as background of your spinner.

In my case it looks like this (`drawable/spinner_background.xml`)

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <selector>
        <item
            android:state_checked="false"
            android:state_pressed="false">
            <layer-list>
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha" />
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha" />
            </layer-list>
        </item>
        <item>
            <layer-list>
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha" />
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha" />
            </layer-list>
        </item>
    </selector>
</inset>
```

and in my styles.xml I use it this way

```
<style name="DxSpinner" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your onViewCreated()

```
spinner.post { spinner.setPadding(0,0,0,0) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the simplest way and also it just work. To decrease left padding of `Spinner`, you can use set padding left to minus so it will move to the left. For example `android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"` This is not a best practice, only a simple hack. Here is a code sample:

```
<Spinner
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"
android:entries="@array/arr_tipe_kendaraan"
android:gravity="left"
android:paddingTop="14dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:prompt="@string/action_sign_in"
android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this issue as well. I was able to solve it with adjusting margin actually instead of padding, so setting android:marginStart="0dp" to the spinner item.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a text-view layout view_spinner_text_view.xml:

   ```
   <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   ```
2. Create the adapter by providing the above layout:

   ```
       ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
           context,
           R.array.my_values,
           R.layout.view_spinner_text_view // <-- this is for the spinner itself
       ).also { adapter ->
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
               android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item // <-- this is for the dropped-down items (you can customize this one as well)
           )
           spinner.adapter = adapter
       }
   ```

Answer (score -2):

This Work for me

```
Spinner spn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn);

spn.setPadding(0, spn.getPaddingTop(), spn.getPaddingRight(), spn.getPaddingBottom());
```