# White Line on the left of my spinner drop-down

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout, spinner

I tried to set margins and padding to 0, but can't get rid of it.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

And here my xml for the dropdown:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:id="@android:id/text1"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:background="@color/j3PreferencesBackground"
                 android:checkMark="@drawable/btn_checkbox_s3_pref_j3"
                 android:layout_height="50dp"
                 android:ellipsize="end"
                 android:gravity="center_vertical"
                 android:minHeight="22dp"
                 android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                 android:paddingRight="10dp"
                 android:maxLines="1"
                 android:textColor="@color/j3Gray70"
                 android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

and for the spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/settingsSetSpinner"
    android:background="@color/j3PreferencesBackground"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/settingsPickerTitle"
    android:defaultValue="0"
    android:entries="@array/import_export_locations"
    />
```

Comment: use Layout Inspector to find that line http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-inspector

Comment: Isn't that some sort of a scrollbar in android itself?

Comment: No, the scrollbar is on the right when scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **padding** with 0dp and **layout_gravity** as left.

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/settingsSetSpinner"
        android:background="@color/j3PreferencesBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
         android:padding="0dp"     
        android:layout_below="@+id/settingsPickerTitle"
        android:defaultValue="0"
        android:entries="@array/import_export_locations"/>
```

For more details refer this link   [Remove Spacing or Padding in android Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164650/remove-spacing-or-padding-in-android-spinner)

Comment: I had already tried setting margin and padding = 0, but hadn't tried the android:layout_gravity="left".  Unfortunately that didn't fix it either  <br> Anyway, thanks for the link.